# Not able to open Twitter in webView Android

Tags: java, android, webview

I am using the following method to open Facebook, Twitter and a Web-Page:

```
private void showAddDialog(String ur) {

        final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.airwebview);

        final WebView webView = (WebView) nagDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.webView_AboutWebsite);
        Button mCancelButton = (Button) nagDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.button_CancelButton);

        mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                nagDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings()
                .setUserAgentString("silly_that_i_have_to_do_this");
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(ur);

        nagDialog.show();
    }
```

I have been able to successfully launch Facebook, and the other web-sites, but could not open the Twitter web-page inside the `WebView`.

I have used the following till now to open Twitter, but yet not succeeded:

`webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
```

What might be the solution for this?

Comment: Why doesn't it load? Does it crash? Or does it just not display the Twitter website?

Answer (score 1):

I check your code, its working fine on my Phone after I set the WebViewClient which override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method to load the redirect URL.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When i have not added the WebViewClient, the twitter made me to redirect to the default web browser which was Chrome in my case.

Check if this help you.